# Tableau pipeline, count ID for calculation only once per calculation

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to make a funnel/pipeline for a data set in Tableau. (Must use tableau as the company has a dashboard portal for internal users)

I have data set up as such:

```
id|app date|group|date start
1 |monday  |3    |   null
2 |monday  |null |   null
3 |tuesday |3    |   wednesday
3 |tuesday |3    |   wednesday
4 |null    |null |   null
```

Due to other features in the data set, rows for this particular problem will be repeated as shown with id 3 above. Also due to other problems in the dashboard I need to retain the other information causing the duplication of rows.

For my pipeline to be accurate, I need to count each instance once.

For example, 4 prospects, 3 applicants, 2 accepted, 1 started in the data above.
I am having difficulty creating the calculations in order to do this.

I have tried several methods but have been unsuccessful thus far.  I am very new to working with tableau calculations and cannot figure out how to use its built in functions to achieve my goal. Is there a way to use SQL statements within a calculation? I would be able to solve my problem if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make calculated fields to count distinct id, ignoring values where a given column is null (which I assume is the criteria for whether the row meets the condition--it wasn't perfectly clear from your question).

These four calculated fields count number of rows that meet each condition per your example.

```
num_prospects: COUNTD(IIF(ISNULL([Id]),NULL,[Id]))
num_applicants: COUNTD(IIF(ISNULL([App Date]),NULL,[Id]))
num_accepted: COUNTD(IIF(ISNULL([Group]),NULL,[Id]))
num_started: COUNTD(IIF(ISNULL([Date Start]),NULL,[Id]))
```

Comment: This is what I ended up realizing after asking the question. Didnt think to just simply put the else as Null though. This will make things cleaner and easier to read for future people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up realizing this solution. Seems to work just fine. "Dummy" will get counted one time on the first duplicate and then ignored every time after that. Then after the countD I just subtract the dummy.

I created a similar calculation for each step in the pipeline (application, decision, enrollment, etc)

```
countd(iif([App Group (group)] <> "Not Admitted",STR([Id]),"Dummy")) -1
```